# missing 1 required positional argument: 'dictVar' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am intro level programmer in Python. I am using an **odeint** function to solve system of ordinary differential equation. I am building the equation structure library(dictionary) which contain variables(a,b,c), trigonometric functions(sin,cos,tan) and arithmetic operators(+ and -) and then later on trying to optimise it using swarm intelligence algorithm. I am just mentioning the part of code where I am getting the error. I have looked to some of the solved questions of the same error but didn't helped me out fix my bug or maybe i am not getting the solution precisely for my problem. Thanks in advance

```
dictVar = {'a':0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub }
t_range = arange(0.0,60.0,1.0)


def odeFunc(Y, t,z, x,dictVar):

    if x[-3] == 192:
        temp1 = 191
    else:
        temp1 = int(x[-3])
    if x[-2] == 192:
        temp2 = 191
    else:
        temp2 = int(x[-2])
    if x[-1] == 192:
        temp3 = 191
    else:
        temp3 = int(x[-1])
    modelOne = modelsOne[temp1]
    modelTwo = modelsTwo[temp2]
    modelThree = modelsThree[temp3]
    return GenModel(Y, x,z, modelOne,modelTwo,modelThree, dictVar)


def GenModel(Y,x,z,modelOne,modelTwo,modelThree, dictVar):
    dydt = zeros_like(Y)
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[0]](dydt[0],x[0]*z[0]*Y[0])
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[1]](dydt[0],x[1]*z[1]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-3]]])
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[2]](dydt[0],x[2]*z[2]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-2]]]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-1]]])
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[3]](dydt[0],x[3]*z[3])

    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[0]](dydt[1],x[4]*z[0]*Y[1])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[1]](dydt[1],x[5]*z[1]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-3]]])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[2]](dydt[1],x[6]*z[2]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-2]]]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-1]]])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[3]](dydt[1],x[7]*z[3])

    dydt[2] = ops[modelThree[0]](dydt[2],x[8]*z[0]*Y[2])
    dydt[2] = ops[modelThree[1]](dydt[2],x[9]*z[1]*Y[dictVar[modelThree[-3]]])
    dydt[2] = ops[modelThree[2]](dydt[2],x[10]*z[2]*Y[dictVar[modelThree[-2]]]*Y[dictVar[modelThree[-1]]])
    dydt[2] = ops[modelThree[3]](dydt[2],x[11]*z[3])

    return dydt
#Equations
def pendulum_equations(w, t):
    T, I, V = w
    dT = 80 - 0.15*T*sin(T) - 0.00002*T*V
    dI = 0.00002*T*V - 0.55*I*cos(T)
    dV = 900*0.55*I - 5.5*V - 0.00002*T*V*tan(V)
    return  dT, dI, dV

result_init = odeint(pendulum_equations, initial_condi, t_range)

# Calculating Sum of Square Error here
def myfunc(xRand):
    result_new = odeint(odeFunc, initial_condi, t_range, args=(xRand,dictVar))
    result_sub = result_new - result_init
    return sum(result_sub*result_sub)
```

Error I'm getting

```
TypeError: odeFunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dictVar'
```

Comment: You have to pass the value of dictVar as in the function declaration you took this as an argument so that while calling that function you have to pass the value of that parameter.

Comment: ```result_new = odeint(odeFunc, initial_condi, t_range, args=(xRand,dictVar))``` should probably be ```result_new = odeint(odeFunc, initial_condi, t_range, xRand,dictVar)```

Comment: @tomgalpin .. No it says "extra argument must be in a tuple" if I remove brackets. I tried it before as well

Comment: That error is when you eventually pass to GenModel .. Pass to odeint the way i explained then create the tuple there and pass that tuple to GenVar

Comment: @tomgalpin I am not getting it. Can you write its code for me. Thanks

Comment: Paste the full error when you get  ""extra argument must be in a tuple""

Comment: @tomgalpin   File "C:\......", line 132, in myfunc result_new = odeint(odeFunc, initial_condi, t_range, xRand,dictVar)                                
  File "C:\.......", line 215, in odeint ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
odepack.error: Extra arguments must be in a tuple

Comment: try:   
`def odeFunc(Y, t,z, args): 
    x,dictVar = args` .  
Within the  definition for odeFunc

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the extra args as a single tuple to within your odeFunc

```
dictVar = {'a':0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub }
t_range = arange(0.0,60.0,1.0)


def odeFunc(Y, t,z, args):
    x,dictVar = args
    if x[-3] == 192:
        temp1 = 191
    else:
        temp1 = int(x[-3])
    if x[-2] == 192:
        temp2 = 191
    else:
        temp2 = int(x[-2])
    if x[-1] == 192:
        temp3 = 191
    else:
        temp3 = int(x[-1])
    modelOne = modelsOne[temp1]
    modelTwo = modelsTwo[temp2]
    modelThree = modelsThree[temp3]
    return GenModel(Y, x,z, modelOne,modelTwo,modelThree, dictVar)


def GenModel(Y,x,z,modelOne,modelTwo,modelThree, dictVar):
    dydt = zeros_like(Y)
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[0]](dydt[0],x[0]*z[0]*Y[0])
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[1]](dydt[0],x[1]*z[1]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-3]]])
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[2]](dydt[0],x[2]*z[2]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-2]]]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-1]]])
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[3]](dydt[0],x[3]*z[3])

    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[0]](dydt[1],x[4]*z[0]*Y[1])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[1]](dydt[1],x[5]*z[1]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-3]]])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[2]](dydt[1],x[6]*z[2]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-2]]]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-1]]])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[3]](dydt[1],x[7]*z[3])

    dydt[2] = ops[modelThree[0]](dydt[2],x[8]*z[0]*Y[2])
    dydt[2] = ops[modelThree[1]](dydt[2],x[9]*z[1]*Y[dictVar[modelThree[-3]]])
    dydt[2] = ops[modelThree[2]](dydt[2],x[10]*z[2]*Y[dictVar[modelThree[-2]]]*Y[dictVar[modelThree[-1]]])
    dydt[2] = ops[modelThree[3]](dydt[2],x[11]*z[3])

    return dydt
#Equations
def pendulum_equations(w, t):
    T, I, V = w
    dT = 80 - 0.15*T*sin(T) - 0.00002*T*V
    dI = 0.00002*T*V - 0.55*I*cos(T)
    dV = 900*0.55*I - 5.5*V - 0.00002*T*V*tan(V)
    return  dT, dI, dV

result_init = odeint(pendulum_equations, initial_condi, t_range)

# Calculating Sum of Square Error here
def myfunc(xRand):
    result_new = odeint(odeFunc, initial_condi, t_range, args=(xRand,dictVar))
    result_sub = result_new - result_init
    return sum(result_sub*result_sub)
```

Comment: line 80, in odeFunc
    x,dictVar = args
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Where does z get calculated ? and how is it passed to odeint ?